# Dojo EdgeToEdgeStoreList with custom ListItem problems

Tags: javascript, dojo

Just faced with dojo templating problem on working with dojo mobile. I want to create custom ListItem for EdgeToEdgeStoreList.

Main html file index.html contains

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.EdgeToEdgeStoreList" data-dojo-props="itemRenderer:app.widgets.CustomListItem" id="list"></div>
```

.js file that sets store in the list:

```
require([ "dojo/ready","dojo/store/Memory", "dojo/parser", "sts/widgets/CustomListItem", "dojox/mobile", "dojo/dom",
        "dijit/registry", "dojox/mobile/ScrollableView", "dojox/mobile/TabBar",
        "dojox/mobile/TabBarButton", "dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeStoreList"], function(ready, Memory,  parser) {

            ready(function() {
                console.log('Dojo ready!');

                store = new Memory({
                    data : [{name:'aaa',surname:'AAA'},{name:'bbb', surname: 'BBB'}],
                    idProperty : 'name'
                });

                dijit.registry.byId('list').setStore(store);
            });

});
```

Widget .js file

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase", 
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dojox/mobile/ListItem",
    "dojo/text!./templates/CustomListItem.html"
    ],
function(declare, WidgetBase, TemplatedMixin, ListItem, template){
    return declare('app.widgets.CustomListItem', [WidgetBase, TemplatedMixin, ListItem],{
    templateString: template
});
```

});

And widget's template: CustomListItem.html

```
<div>
    <div>TEST TEST</div>
</div>
```

Does anybody knows why if I'm using such order in the widget declaration (WidgetBase, TemplatedMixin, ListItem), dojo tries to render ListItem default template but if I swap TemplatedMixi and ListItem (WidgetBase, ListItem, TemplatedMixin), everything work correctly? I didn't even know that inheritance order is important for dojo.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the exact root explanation of your issue but the fact is that ListItem already inherits itself from _WidgetBase so I would say there is no reason from having your own class duplicate that inheritance.

```
declare('app.widgets.CustomListItem', [ListItem, TemplatedMixin],{});
```

should work and is simpler?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting this strange behaviour with swapping ListItem and TemplateMixin

Comment: Well there is no reason swapping them. ListItem is really the class your extend and TemplatedMixin the mixin, so it is "normal" for it to be second in the list.